# create java library that don't display code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface

I want to create a java library that contains the view, adapter, SQLite, libraries and etc...
but I want the user can't access my library's code.
Actually see an interface of method names just for calling.
how can I do it?

Comment: Is it concern regarding your source code? Like you want to protect your source code not to be revealed?

Comment: @Sajjad Yes I want to protect code disclosure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple, robust way to prevent decompilation of Java classes. However, there are many 'obfuscator' tools for Java that come pretty close in practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to fully protect your source code, especially in Java. You can just make it hard for others to get to your source code.

**First method:** One major technique is code obfuscation using tools like `Proguard`. You can enable it by adding the attribute `minifyEnabled true` to your gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Using this technique, you have to exclude the classes to which user needs to interact. In the proguard config file:

```
-keep class com.example.myapp.ThisParticularClass
```

**Second method:** Another technique that you can use is adding a bit of C/C++ code to your library. You can do some specific tasks like building Strings, special characters, storing keys and numbers in a C/C++ class and then in your java, call those classes.

**Third method:** While it seems stupid, but it really works. A lot of programmers who decompile your  code are not serious enough to spend a lot of time understanding your code. So you can add extra boilerplate code to your project/library by using interfaces, intermediate methods, extra calls and a bunch of other innovative methods.